# Creating navigation code-first results in the error: does not declare a navigation property with the name

Tags: asp.net

```
query.Include("Store_Location").Load();
```

throws:

An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Model.Order' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Store_Location'.

I used the following code in order to create the navigation code-first:

```
public partial class Order
{

    public Nullable<int> Store_Location_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Store_Location Store_Location { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

}



public partial class Store_Location
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]

}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/relationships

Do I need to use the designer? Is there anything I need to do in order for the navigation to be created?

Comment: Why are you using partial classes? It does not seem to be a code-first approach. Also in C# you should use PascalCasing for class names and property names like this: 
public class StoreLocation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your database with code first approach, then your entities should not be partial classes. Define them like this:

```
public class Order
{
    public int? StoreLocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual StoreLocation StoreLocation { get; set; }
}


public class StoreLocation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should create a DbContext class:

```
 public class StoreDbContext : DbContext
 {
        public StoreDbContext(DbContextOptions<StoreDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<StoreLocation> StoreLocations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
 }
```

After creating a context you can use the ef commands to create your database. You can read more about ef core here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli

If you define your classes like I did above, you can include your navigation properties strongly typed like this:

```
query.Include(order => order.StoreLocation);
```